# Woocommerce is returning empty array list while fetching shipping methods

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am building a custom shipping method plugin for which i need to access shipping method variables .

```
      echo  "<pre>";
        print_r( $woocommerce->shipping->get_shipping_methods);

      echo"</pre>";
```

doing this in my plugin is returning an empty set or array 
while,

```
echo  "<pre>";
    print_r( $woocommerce->shipping->get_shipping_methods);

  echo"</pre>";
```

returns expected value(available shipping methods)
any ideas is it due to some kind of error or what ?

here is shipping object which am getting -->

```
WC_Shipping Object
(
    [enabled] => 1
    [shipping_methods] => Array
        (
        )

    [shipping_total] => 0
    [shipping_taxes] => Array
        (
        )

    [shipping_label] => 
    [shipping_classes] => Array
        (
        )

    [packages] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Answer (score 6):

I am using the following snippet: 
`$shipping_methods = $woocommerce->shipping->load_shipping_methods();`

This returns the shipping methods for me.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any difference between the two blocks of code that you posted but I think the correct way of doing this should be to make a function call rather than accessing it as a property of the class.

```
echo  "<pre>";

print_r( $woocommerce->shipping->get_shipping_methods() );

echo "</pre>";
```

(Note the brackets just after get_shipping_methods)

Comment: sorry that was mistake i did with my brackets on is $woocommerce->shipping->get_shipping_methods() still i am getting an empty array